# Can AWS AppSync follow server based architecture?

Tags: graphql, aws-appsync

I see it supports lambda which is serverless, can AppSync support server based architecture, where a dedicated server serves GraphQL requests ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a HTTP type datasource to connect to an EC2 instance. These are all the data sources you can use: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/APIReference/API_DataSource.html

Comment: thanks, but this will add network hop latency to my service.

Comment: The only other way is to use a lambda proxy (see here: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/appsync-microservices/). If performance is paramount then you can also consider deploying and managing Apollo server instead of using AppSync (which is what AppSync uses under the hood), but then maybe the added latency of a graphql proxy might not be what you're after anyway if the use case is so sensitive to latency.